# SignalR doesn't work while published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, signalr, .net-6.0

My .NET Core 6 code runs perfectly on Visual Studio 2022, but when my app is published to a server running IIS, my SignalR functionality stops working.

JavaScript:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/checkproduct").build();
```

program.cs:

```
app.MapHub<ProductHub>("/checkproduct");
```

Error Message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) signalr.js:3082
> [2024-01-22T06:11:53.892Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Not Found
> [2024-01-22T06:11:53.893Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Not Found

Comment: At your url you are acessing your app?

Comment: Where is your signalR server hosted? In your javascript, you have to specify the full url of the signalR server(for example, http://<HostName>:<port>/checkproduct).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In Windows Features make sure u have checked the WebSocket Protocol and the issue will be resolved

Comment: it is installed. but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your issue, I referred [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and create simple demo, I publish it on IIS and it works fine.
Taking the example in the documentation, make sure your static resource directory looks like this:
​[image]

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.